# Type coercions in finset

Tags: types, coq

I have this definition, which defines a list of pairs of nats and an element of a subset of some universal type U using the finset library.

```
Definition my_list {U : finType} (E : {set U}) : Type := 
  let P u := mem u E in
  list (nat * {x | P x}).
```

I want a projection function as follows:

```
Context {U : finType}.
Variable E1 E2 : {set U}.

Lemma in_E1_pair (x : nat*{x : U | mem x (E1 :|: E2)}) :
  (val (snd x)) \in E1 = true -> nat*{x : U | mem x E1}.
Proof.
  ...
Defined.

Program Fixpoint proj1_set (m_list : my_list (E1 :|: E2))
  : my_list E1 :=
  match my_list with
  | [] => []
  | x :: tl => 
      match ((val (snd x)) \in E1) with
      | true => (in_E1_pair x _) :: proj1_set tl
      | _ => proj1_set tl
      end
  end
```

This works to get the sub list of elements in E1 and set the type of these elements to `nat * {x : U | mem x E1}`, which is exactly what I want. However, the fact that I need to use either `Program` or the convoy pattern (which I tried as well) makes this function very complex to use in later proofs.

Is there any other way to define this in a simpler way such that I still have the same return type but the function is not so unwieldy in proofs? I thought perhaps something with `filter` and then somehow using a lemma to coerce to the type. Or perhaps a different way of defining `my_list` would be beneficial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to leave the proof of `val x.2 \in E1` as a hole for `Program` to fill in the case of the branch where it holds; you can provide it explicitly instead. (I changed some minor things to make it compile and fit in with the mathcomp style.)

```
From mathcomp Require Import all_ssreflect.

Definition my_list {U : finType} (E : {set U}) : Type :=
  seq (nat * {x | x \in E}).

Context {U : finType}.
Variable E1 E2 : {set U}.

Lemma in_E1_pair (x : nat * {x : U | x \in (E1 :|: E2)}) :
  val x.2 \in E1 -> nat * {x : U | x \in E1}.
Proof.
Admitted.

Fixpoint proj1_set (w : my_list (E1 :|: E2)) : my_list E1 :=
  match w with
  | [::] => [::]
  | x :: tl =>
      match boolP (val x.2 \in E1) with
      | AltTrue p => (in_E1_pair x p) :: proj1_set tl
      | _ => proj1_set tl
      end
  end.
```

I don't know whether this is less unwieldy in proofs since you didn't provide an example (although I expect it is).

Also, this kind of construction, even the simplified one I provided, is always going to be annoying. I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish, so I can't give you a better alternative. But ideally you would have some raw non-dependent type without whatever properties you want and then an enhanced type that is just the raw version plus a proof it has the desired property, like so:

```
Parameter rawT : Type.
Parameter good : rawT -> bool. (* or Prop, if the property is not decidable *)
Record T := makeT {
  rawT_of_T :> rawT;
  _ : good rawT_of_T;
}.
Canonical T_subType := [subType for rawT_of_T].
```

Then define all of your functions (like `proj1_set`) on `rawT` inputs and outputs, prove a lemma to the effect that when the input is in `T`, the output is as well, and proceed from there. (Note that `rawT_of_T` is a coercion, so any function that expects something of type `rawT` and receives something of type `T` will know what to do with it.)

---

Here is how I would define your list type using the raw strategy I proposed above:

```
From mathcomp Require Import all_ssreflect.

(* Default implicit arguments as standard in mathcomp *)
Set Implicit Arguments.
Unset Strict Implicit.
Unset Printing Implicit Defensive.

Context (U : finType).

(* no conditions on which elements of U are in rawMylist *)
Definition rawMylist : Type := seq (nat * U).

Definition good (E : {set U}) (w : rawMylist) : bool :=
  unzip2 w \subset E.

(* should be equivalent to your dependent definition of my_list *)
Record mylist (E : {set U}) : Type := mkMylist {
  rawMylist_of_mylist :> rawMylist;
  _ : good E rawMylist_of_mylist;
}.

(* like the seq filter function, but remembering the nat part of rawMylist *)
Fixpoint rawMylist_filter (a : pred U) (w : rawMylist) : rawMylist :=
  if w is hd :: tl then
    if a hd.2 then
      hd :: rawMylist_filter a tl
    else
      rawMylist_filter a tl
  else
    [::].

(* what your in_E1_pair looks like in this framing *)
(* there is probably a less meandering proof that doesn't use subsetP so much,
but at least this was fast to prove *)
Lemma goodUl (E1 E2 : {set U}) (w : mylist (E1 :|: E2)) :
  good E1 (rawMylist_filter (fun x => x \in E1) w).
Proof.
  case: w => /=; rewrite /good.
  elim=> /= [|hd tl IH].
    by move=> _; apply/subsetP => u /[!in_nil].
  case: ifP => /= [hdinE1|nhdinE1] /subsetP hdtlinE12.
    apply/subsetP => u /[!inE] /orP [/eqP -> //|/(@subsetP _ _ E1)].
    apply; apply: IH.
    apply/subsetP => {}u uintl.
    apply: hdtlinE12.
    by rewrite inE uintl orbT.
  apply: IH.
  apply/subsetP => u uintl.
  apply: hdtlinE12.
  by rewrite inE uintl orbT.
Qed.

(* what your proj1_set looks like in this framing *)
Definition rawMylist_proj1 (E1 E2 : {set U}) (w : mylist (E1 :|: E2))
    : mylist E1 :=
  mkMylist (goodUl w).
```

This is much easier to deal with than your version, because there is a clear separation between informative types you can use for computation (`rawMylist`) and dependent types you can use for proofs. I'm still using dependent types but there is a trivial way of "forgetting" the dependent, non-informative part to obtain a simpler object.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I should have provided an example of what I am trying to show. One property I am trying to show is that if the original my_list has the property of being increasing (the nats of the list elements increase) which I defined with an inductive type with two constructors, the function will preserve that property. 

If I understand your explanation correctly, my `rawT` would be `my_list` and `good` would test if it has this increasing property. Then I could show that if the input is in `T`, with the property, the output would be in `T` too.

Comment: @anonymous12345677654 no, that is not what I meant. See my edited answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed response. I will try to use this formulation to see if it makes it easier to prove that the `rawMylist_proj1` preserves this increasing property.

Comment: This helped quite a bit, as I now only have to show the property for the underlying 'raw' type. Would you perhaps have a resource for reading more into defining these structures and subtypes? For example, now I'm trying to show that `mylist (E1 :|: E2)` and `mylist (E2 :|: E1)` should be equivalent, as there is a lemma stating that `E1 :|: E2 = E2 :|: E1`

Comment: Great, that's the idea! You can easily prove `E1 = E2 -> mylist E1 = mylist E2`, just rewrite with `E1 = E2`. As for resources, I learned this through an unofficial teacher, but I think it should be explained in the [MathComp book](https://math-comp.github.io/mcb/). You can also play with my [formalization of a kind of Kripke model](https://gitlab.com/ana-borges/QRC1-Coq/-/blob/master/theories/KripkeSemantics.v#L117) or of [UTC dates and times](https://gitlab.com/formalv/formalv/-/blob/dev/theories/time/calendar.v#L192), both of which use this technique. See also the corresponding READMEs.